# Calling varargs method mixing elements and array of elements does not work

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have a method with the following signature:

```
public void foo(String... params);
```

So all of these calls are valid:

```
foo("Peter", "John");
foo(new String[] { "Peter", "John" });
```

But why is this one not valid?

```
foo("Peter", new String[] { "John" });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

> The three periods after the final
>   parameter's type indicate that the
>   final argument may be passed as an
>   array ***or*** as a sequence of arguments.

You can't pass an argument **and** an array.

Comment: And it is a good thing that you can't. Since Java5 the rules for resolving methods have already become too tricky when autoboxing, varargs, and arrays come into play.

Answer (score 2):

That's because in fact you try to pass Array containing String and another Array.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not the same thing. You just can't mix and match like that. The invalid one in your example would work with a function signature like this:

```
public void foo(String head, String ... tail)
```

Answer (score 0):

This method

```
public void foo(String... params);
```

is just a convenience version of this one:

```
public void foo(String[] params);
```

And hence you can call it with a variable number of Strings (that will be converted to a String array by the compiler) or a String array, but a combination won't work, by design.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. What if you had a method like this:

```
public void foo(Object... objects);
```

And tried to call it like this:

```
foo("bar", new Object[] { "baz" });
```

Should the `Object[]` in the second position be treated as a single `Object` in the varargs call or should it be "expanded"? This would lead to very confusing behavior.